# How to check SSL cert a mail server using SMTP commands

Tags: email, ssl, smtp

Anyone know how open a SMTP conversation with a mail server (over the SSL port, and not 25/110) and view info for the SSL cert is it, using SMTP commands?

Comment: Would be helpfull to know which platform you are using for the SMTP server?

Comment: Platform doesn't matter really in this case. He's asking how to connect remotely to a server and view info on its SSL certs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not going to be able to get any useful information only using SMTP commands. You'll need to use something that understands SSL, like OpenSSL's s_client. Something like this should work:

```
$ openssl s_client -starttls smtp -crlf -connect 1.1.1.1:25
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is an Exchange server, you can also try https://www.testexchangeconnectivity.com/